# Jsch certificate based authentication and login Auth cancel

Tags: authentication, ssh, jsch

Jsch, private.ppk based login.

Currently i have following code to ssh login but getting exception due to does not provide key.

Following is my error i am getting

```
om.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel


 JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user_name, host, 22);


        UserInfo ui = new SSHUserInfo(password, true);
        session.setUserInfo(ui);
        //connect to remove server
        session.connect();

        //sudo login bamboo
        if (null != session && session.isConnected()) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
JSch jsch = new JSch();

// Here privateKey is a file path like "/home/me/.ssh/secret_rsa "
// passphrase is passed as a string like "mysecr"
jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, passphrase);

session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
// Or yes, up to you. If yes, JSch locks to the server identity so it cannot
// be swapped by another with the same IP.

session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("shell");
out = channel.getOutputStream();
channel.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

The file suffix ".ppk" means that you are trying to use Putty's private key, I guess.

JSch has supported the Putty's private keys since 0.1.49,
and if your key is ciphered, you must install  "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files"[1] on your environment.

And then, if you are using Pageant usually, you may be interested in trying jsch-agent-proxy[2].

```
[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html
[2] https://github.com/ymnk/jsch-agent-proxy
```